# Checking for custom file using puppet

Tags: puppet

Part of my puppet manifest checks for the existence of a custom `sshd_config`. If one is found, I use that. If it's not then I use my default. I'm just wondering if there is a more "puppet" way of doing this

```
if file("/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/files/${::fqdn}/etc/ssh/sshd_config", '/dev/null') != '' {
  $sshd_config_source = "puppet:///private/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
} else {
  $sshd_config_source = "puppet:///public/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
}

file { '/etc/ssh/sshd_config':
  ensure => 'present',
  mode   => '600',
  source => $sshd_config_source,
  notify => Service['sshd'],
}
```

This code works but it's a little odd as `file` I have to give it the full path on the puppet master but when assigning `$sshd_config_source` I have to use the puppet fileserver path (`puppet:///private/etc...`).

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: My option to manage config file in puppet is, you shouldn't try to avoid it when the file is exist. For example, it will be good idea to create `ssh_config.erb` file to customise it with different users. You need prepare the code to override it always, if it is under control of puppet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little known feature of the `file` type that you can supply multiple [source](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-source) values.

From the docs:

> Multiple source values can be specified as an array, and Puppet will use the first source that exists. This can be used to serve different files to different system types:

```
file { "/etc/nfs.conf":
  source => [
    "puppet:///modules/nfs/conf.$host",
    "puppet:///modules/nfs/conf.$operatingsystem",
    "puppet:///modules/nfs/conf"
  ]
}
```

So you should just specify both the specific and the generic file URL, in that order, and Puppet will do the right thing for you.